# How to tell chef to not untar a tarball if it has already been extracted?

Tags: bash, chef-infra

In my chef code, I am unpacking a tarball in a specific directory using an "execute" resource" . How do I write my code so that it only unpacks my tarball if the files within the tarball are not all present within the directory? In other words, do not do anything if the tarball has already been unpacked.

This is what I have so far:

```
execute 'unpack' do 
  command "unzip #{working_dir}/config.zip -d #{working_dir}"
  not_if # not if the files and directories within config.zip are already within "working_dir"
```

end

Answer (score 3):

In Chef client 15 and above, there is an `archive_file` [resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/) which can be used. Example:

```rb
archive_file "#{working_dir}/config.zip" do
  destination working_dir
  overwrite false          # Default behaviour
  action :extract
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach here (assuming that your `config.zip` is managed in such a way that its timestamp genuinely reflects the point in time when a new version is pushed out) is to maintain a success marker, and check whether that marker is newer than `config.zip`:

```rb
execute 'unpack' do 
  command "unzip #{working_dir}/config.zip -d #{working_dir} && touch #{working_dir}/.unpack"
  not_if "test #{working_dir}/.unpack -nt #{working_dir}/config.zip"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
execute "#{working_dir}/config.zip" do
    command "unzip #{working_dir}/config.zip -d #{working_dir}"
    not_if do
      ::File.exist?("#{working_dir}/somefile")
    end
  end
```

I agree with [Seshadri C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968097/seshadri-c) use the `archive_file` resource

https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/